# GetStream Chat React native: [Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I have react native project with below version details and implement the GetSream Chat with below version.

"react-native": "0.62.2",
"stream-chat-react-native": "^1.3.3"

Now when i create **chatClient.setUser** it work very fine if my debugger is on in app. Here is the link for official doc to initiate the user https://getstream.io/chat/docs/init_and_users/?language=js

[image]

But now suppose i off the debugger then its giving me the below error and it wont open any channel.

> [Error: crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See
> https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported]

If need any more information please let me know.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes for dependencies:

> You will need to install LinusU/react-native-get-random-values and add this line import 'react-native-get-random-values'; to your index.js

See the docs for more details: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native/wiki/Upgrade-helper#dependency-changes

Comment: Yes, i have solved this issues by doing this. But i dont know this strange behaviour the app is worked fine if i attached the debugger!. Anyways i got this soltions from given link before and just forgot to update. So this solution works for me. Thanks @ferhat